# How does a Lehmer Sieve work?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computer-science, math-history, factoring, sieve-theory

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_sieve

Apparently a Lehmer Sieve was a mechanical device that used chains and pulleys to factor numbers and solve diophantine equations. It once was able to factor $2^{93} + 1 = 3 \times 3 \times 529510939 \times 715827883 \times 2903110321$ in just 3 seconds according the book, Lehmer's Machine(1960). Just looking at its workings, and with a quick Google search I see several examples, but no explanations. Can anyone give me an explanation for how the setup for the device can be used to calculations so quickly?

Edit:
Say I want to build one (because who doesn't?), how hard would this be with pulleys and loops of paper/fabric? How would I construct/set up it to do math? Mathematical explanations are good, but does anyone have any engineering diagrams or the like? I would love to make one. Links to sites that I may have missed would also be widely appreciated.

Comment: Brillhart gave a talk about this at our university once. IIRC the numbers of links on the chains where prime numbers. The links corresponding to quadratic residues modulo that prime had spikes or something, so that when you turned the crank, and reached a position such that the links on the top would be quadratic residues on all the links, then that would cause the rotation to stop. When that happened there was a reasonably high chance that you had found a factor.

Comment: (cont'd) May be it was just trying to write the number as a diffence of two squares, and if a number is a QR modulo a large set of primes, then it is likely to be a square? I'm afraid I don't remember the route from a stalled position to a potential factor. What I do remember is that the reason to replace the bicycle chains with film was that when they wanted to turn the crank faster, the loosely hanging chains would take a figure 8 shape, and jam the machine.

Comment: Then does it have many many chains? one for 2, one for 3, one for 5 etc, etc? How does one use this for factoring specific numbers?

Comment: Found a paper that describes building one with lego, has some pictures and diagrams, might be useful: http://www.brickshelf.com/gallery/ulimy/Computer/lehmer.pdf

Comment: @JasonConti I saw this but it didnt explain how exactly this configuration did the math that was explained in the same paper.

Comment: looks like I might have to reverse engineer it myself. Well that should be fun.

Comment: It also looks like the lego paper is the best you can get; quite impressive.

Comment: @Asimov, not sure if you're still working on this, but here's a different Lehmer paper I found that gives a detailed mechanical description with examples: [http://cr.yp.to/bib/1928/lehmer.pdf](http://cr.yp.to/bib/1928/lehmer.pdf) But maybe you've already seen this.

Comment: @jrodatus  I had not been working on this, but this document is much better than the other. Thank you so much. Seriously helpful.